# Refugees situation in Macedonia

Tags: safety, road-trips, event-based-effects, macedonia, refugees

I am travelling to Macedonia for a roadtrip in May. I am flying to Skopje and planning to travel by the west side down to Ohrid and then return back to Skopje through the middle part of the country.

I heard about refugees crisis in Macedonia. Is there something I have to be aware about?

Comment: You probably should keep track of what's happening 'right now'. I traveled from Thessaloniki to Skopje to Pristina a few weeks ago. And though what I think is the largest refugee camp in Mainland Europe is right on the border of Greece and Macedonia, along the highway from Thessaloniki, I noticed none of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you have to be aware. But there is no need for panic. Carry your papers with you at all times.

- In the summer of 2015, some roads and rail lines along the [balkan route](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_migrant_crisis#Migrant_routes.2C_development.2C_and_responses_in_individual_countries) were closed because of refugee columns. For safety reasons, and also to discourage helpers from giving refugees a lift.
- Likewise border crossings were closed to *legitimate* traffic because there were refugees trying to cross.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I am not planning to cross the border. I am landing in Skopje and planning to take the car there. Is that still valid? As far as I understand from your response, if the are "troubles" on the road, it will be closed by the authorities, right? In regards to papers -- I have Lithuania citizenship and we do not need any visas while travelling to Macedonia. Are there some other documents I have to have anyway?

Comment: @MaksimSorokin, predictions regarding the future are always difficult, and Macedonia may or may not react the way Hungary did last year. I see no likelihood that Macedonia would deliberately close their borders to EU citizens. I see the possibility that they would close some roads and border crossings because they can't sort things out in the chaos.